# Google custom search change sort on search start callback

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I need to change the results ordering via `setSearchStartingCallback`.

This is to order the results by date if user is on "news" refinement (tab).

```
customSearchControl.setSearchStartingCallback(this, function(sc, searcher, query) {
     document.getElementById('SearchForm_Search').value = query;              
});
```

- https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't a setting to this using the google-custom-search api, I ended up using custom javascript magic